# XPath : How do I reference all the children of an element WITHOUT using * (asterisk)?

Tags: xpath, oracle11g, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I'm currently working on an Oracle SOA project and I'm having problems mapping my incoming message to another message.  I'm new to SOA and the Oracle toolset.  I'm using JDeveloper, and here are the versions listed in the "About" tab:

```
ADF Business Components   11.1.1.62.29
BPMN Editor               11.1.1.6.0.15.53
Java(TM) Platform         1.6.0_24
Oracle IDE                11.1.1.6.38.62.29
SOA Composite Editor      11.1.1.6.0.15.53
Team Productivity Center  11.1.1.6.38.61.92
Versioning Support        11.1.1.6.38.62.29
```

My incoming message is an error message that wraps failed messages from other services.  The message is formatted as follows:

```
<Error>
   <code />
   <service />
   ...
   <Message>
       [ORIGINAL MESSAGE HERE]
   </Message>
</Error>
```

I need to map the contents of Message to another message type.  The message tag contains serialized XML created by the `bea:serialize` function.  The contents of that message tag can vary depending on the service that built the error message and sent it.  In my XSL file that handles the mapping, message is mapped using the function `get-content-as-string function` using the expression:

```
/error-v1:Error/Message
```

The problem with this is that the Message tag gets copied as well, where I really just want its contents.  I've tried using `/error-v1:Error/Message/*`, but JDeveloper produces an error stating that `*` is not a valid node.  If I ignore the error and deploy, the process errors out when the mapping occurs.  I've also tried using `/error-v1:Error/Message/child::*`, but this produces the same error.

All references I've found online say that the above should work, but I can't seem to find a solution that works that with SOA as well.  Suggestions?

Comment: I'm very tempted to remove the tag "XPath" from this question, because it seems to be a question about some sub-standard variant of XPath supported by a particular product. Knowing XPath does not enable you to answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps.  My thought process was that JDeveloper may be supporting an older version, but I included it anyway since the dialog specifically prompts for an XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `/error-v1:Error/Message/text()` - you want the inner text of the `Message` tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this only produces an empty string.  If I remove `/text()` I see the serialized XML ( `<` signs are escaped to `$lt;`), so I know my message isn't blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
/error-v1:Error/Message/node()

Comment: Unfortunately I receive an error from JDeveloper stating that `node` is not a valid element.  I tried this along with `text()`, but neither seem to work.  I may need to find a SOA expert as Oracle SOA may be using a non-standard variation.